# Having trouble returning Javascript Object Selenium C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So basically what I am trying to do is setup a proxy to intercept my call to a website and put a script tag in the header to catch javascript bugs using fiddler's proxy library.  Which looks like this:

```
<script>
    window.__webdriver_javascript_errors = []; 
    window.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, line) 
                    { window.__webdriver_javascript_errors.push(errorMsg + ' (found at ' + url + ', line ' + line + ')'); };
</script>
```

That all works great and it is catching bugs before the page loads.  My issue is when I go to the page I can't actually return the javascript object from the page.

```
        public static IList<string> GetJavaScriptErrors(IWebDriver driver, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            string errorRetrievalScript = "var errorList = window.__webdriver_javascript_errors; window.__webdriver_javascript_errors = []; return errorList;";
            DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.Add(timeout);
            List<string> errorList = new List<string>();
            IJavaScriptExecutor executor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
            List<object> returnedList = executor.ExecuteScript(errorRetrievalScript) as List<object>;
            while (returnedList == null && DateTime.Now < endTime)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
                returnedList = executor.ExecuteScript(errorRetrievalScript) as List<object>;
            }

            if (returnedList == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (object returnedError in returnedList)
                {
                    errorList.Add(returnedError.ToString());
                }
            }

            return errorList;
        }
```

Now when I run this, my **returnedList** never ever gets the **errorRetrievalScript** returned to it.  I cannot seem to figure out why I always get null returned.

The weirdness is, before I run the executor for javascript if I go to Firefox and type in

> window.__webdriver_javascript_errors

All the errors show up just fine, but the second I hit that executor the errors vanish, which is what I want to happen, and that works!  But the return never returns anything.

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

The selenium, and browsers versions I am using are:

Firefox: 47.0.1

Chrome: 51.0.2704.103

IE: 11.420.10586.0

Selenium: 2.53.1

Comment: Which version of Firefox and driver are you using ?

Comment: I just updated it!  Sorry I should've put that in to begin with.

Comment: What happens if you change your retrieval script to: `var errorList = webdriver_javascript_errors.slice(); window.__webdriver_javascript_errors = []; return errorList;` ? There may be a bug in the JavaScript code in the blog post you copied the technique from.

Comment: Alternatively, you can omit the cast of the return value from `ExecuteScript`, set a breakpoint in the debugger, and see what it's actually returning. You may be getting a result that isn't a `List<object>`, but casting using the `as` operator coalesces it to `null`.

Comment: Hey thank you a ton it was the casting!  If you write an answer to this from these two comments let me give you the correct answer and an upvote.  I really appreciate your help, I did not know that about casting either, I will have to google and read up on how C# casting works for objects that can't convert.  Again thank you again, and please let me give you some points!